# How to use full text search for unknown number of children of a field in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have a document with one field `description` like this:

```
{
  "_id": "item0",
  "description": {
    "parlist": [
      {
        "listitem": {
          "text": {
            "child": "page rous lady",
            "keyword": "officer e"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "listitem": {
          "text": "shepherd noble "
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to create text index on `description` and search for specific word? I don't know how depth can `description` go and how many children will description have. I tried with index creation like this:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({description:"text"})
```

and then for query like this:

```
db.collection.runCommand("text",{$search:"shepherd"})
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply [build an text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) for all text field:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "$**": "text" })
```

Then search with keyword [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text):

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "shepherd" } } )
```

Comment: There are many other fields also, but I would like to search only from `description` field. if I use `db.collection.ensureIndex({ "$**": "text" })` index, it will return result even it content in other field rather than `description`.

Comment: Did some search and unfortunately can't find a way to do that... people in this post end up using the way above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239298/create-text-index-on-sub-document-field-wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Text-indexes do not work on full sub-documents, but you can create a text index which includes more than one field:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
     {
         "description.parlist.listitem.text": "text",
         "description.parlist.listitem.text.child": "text",
         "description.parlist.listitem.text.keyword": "text"
     }
)
```